# Doesn't find the template when I am using variable rules (jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: page_name .)

Tags: python, flask

all the html files are in the Template folder and all the .js and .css files are in static folder

The following code is working

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
    app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def my_home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/about.html')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')
```

But when I am using variable rules, it doesn't work:

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: page_name

```
    @app.route('/<string:page_name>')
    def html_page(page_name):
        return render_template('page_name')
```

Answer (score 1):

you pass page_name as a string not as an actual value of `page_name`

instead Try:

```py
return render_template(page_name)
```